# how to use lane changing model SL2015 in flow?

Tags: flow-project

When I try to run any scenario such as loop or highway using SL2015 as lane change model I get the following error: Error: value '0' must be greater than or equal to minExclusive facet value '0'
In file 'X/flow/flow/core/kernel/scenario/debug/cfg/highway_example_20190725-1726581564100818.2933977.add.xml'
At line/column 4/430.

I have enabled the sub-lane using 'lateral_resolution'. If I use LC2013 which is lane jump then everything works. Only smooth lane change configuration is causing the error. Below is the generated add.xml file.

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<additional xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://sumo.dlr.de/xsd/additional_file.xsd">
  <vType accel="2.6" carFollowModel="IDM" decel="4.5" id="human" impatience="0.5" laneChangeModel="SL2015" lcAccelLat="1.0" lcAssertive="1" lcCooperative="1.0" lcImpatience="0" lcKeepRight="1.0" lcLookaheadLeft="2.0" lcPushy="0" lcPushyGap="0.6" lcSpeedGain="1.0" lcSpeedGainRight="1.0" lcStrategic="1.0" lcSublane="1.0" lcTimeToImpatience="inf" maxSpeed="30" minGap="2.5" sigma="0.5" speedDev="0.1" speedFactor="1.0" tau="1.0"/>
</additional>
```

Answer (score 0):

sorry for this difficulty! We haven't explored using this model yet but will put it on our list of things to support in the next release.